# About SKU in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.5, magento-1.6

I want to know if i created one simple product with e.g sku:YJR
then i have to create the same product as bundle product with same sku, then it create any problem in future, if not then what's the rightway ?
Any guidence is accepted.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions abut Magento should be asked on [magento.se]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about business operations, specifically store/inventory management and therefore might be more applicable over in magento.stackexchange

Answer (score 14):

Firstly I would like to tell you something about : SKU

SKU StockKeeping Unit, is a unique identification code, usually alphanumeric. It allows a particular product to be tracked for inventory purposes. Typically, an SKU (pronounced with the individual letters or as SKYEW) is associated with any purchasable item in a store or catalog. You can choose any format you like for SKU but usually there is some system for choosing numbers, for example, a woman’s blouse of a particular style and size might have an SKU of “3726-8,” meaning “Style 3726, size 8.”

SKU is unique identification code.You can not create a product a with already existed SKU its not possible.

Hope this one is useful for you

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive answer.